# Transfer all mails of specific label to another mail (apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'd like to create a script to transfer emails from a specific label to another email address.

I've started to write my code but there must be an error somewhere as I'm not getting any mail from my Logger.log.

Can you please help me with this?

```
function searchLabels() {
   // 1. Declaration of constants and variables
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var label, threads, msgs;
   var mail = "test@123.com"

   // 2. Get messages from label
   label = ui.prompt("Write your label here : ");
   threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label.getResponseText());
   msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

   // 3. Transfer msgs to another mail
   for (let i = 0; i < msgs.length; i ++){
     GmailApp.sendEmail(mail,msgs[i]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official document of `getMessagesForThreads(threads)` says as follows.

> Return
> `GmailMessage[][]` — an array of arrays of messages, where each item in the outer array corresponds to a thread and the inner array contains the messages in that thread

In your script, `msgs[i]` is an array including the messages. And also, in the case of `GmailApp.sendEmail(mail,msgs[i]);`, the arguments are `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

And, when you want to transfer the messages, I thought that `forward(recipient)` of Class GmailMessage might be able to be used.

If you want to achieve "Transfer all mails of specific label to another mail" by including these modification points, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (let i = 0; i < msgs.length; i ++){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(mail,msgs[i]);
}
```

#### To:

```
for (let i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
    msgs[i][j].forward(mail);
  }
}
```

or

```
msgs.forEach(thread => {
  thread.forEach(message => {
    message.forward(mail);
  });
});
```

#### References:

- [getMessagesForThreads(threads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getmessagesforthreadsthreads)
- [forward(recipient)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forwardrecipient)

Comment: Thanks for your help Tanaike. Indeed, sending the message now works. Given that some emails contain replies from other users, is it possible to "capture" their email addresses and, when forwarding, have exactly the same thing? I did a test with the code above and I'm still the sender.

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying. From `Indeed, sending the message now works.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Given that some emails contain replies from other users, is it possible to "capture" their email addresses and, when forwarding, have exactly the same thing?`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @devMethodes But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?